# AWS node.js SDK getting 'Access Denied' using AWS example

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm new at AWS, maybe I'm missing something obvious so help is required.

I have 2 version of code, the only different is passing bucket as a 4 chars string vs 5 chars. getting different response from aws.
why is that?

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3(); 

s3.createBucket({Bucket: 'node4'}, function() {
  var params = {Bucket: 'node4', Key: 'myKey', Body: 'Hello!'};
  s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err)       
          console.log(err)     
      else
        console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey");   
   });
});
```

running the app.js:

```
➜  aws  node app.js
{ [AllAccessDisabled: All access to this object has been disabled]
  message: 'All access to this object has been disabled',
  code: 'AllAccessDisabled',
  region: null,
  time: Fri Feb 05 2016 20:45:11 GMT+0200 (IST),
  requestId: 'somerequestId',
  extendedRequestId: 'someextendedRequestId',
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 30 }
```

second code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3(); 

s3.createBucket({Bucket: 'node4e'}, function() {
  var params = {Bucket: 'node4e', Key: 'myKey', Body: 'Hello!'};
  s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err)       
          console.log(err)     
      else
        console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey");   
   });
});
```

running the app.js:

```
➜  aws  node app.js
Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the only different is passing bucket as a 4 chars string vs 5 chars

Actually the only difference is that you don't have write access to the bucket named 'node4' and you do have access to a bucket named 'node4e'. Did you check to see if both buckets were actually created successfully? I notice you aren't checking for errors in the `createBucket()` call, just the `putObject()` call.

Those are fairly generic bucket names you are using, I wouldn't be surprised if the one that is failing, 'node4', is already in use by another AWS account.

Comment: both buckets did not exist, at least not on my account. Can't really test trying to create another user's bucket as I do no have such an example. Running the same working test twice with the same response 'Successfully', so maybe having the bucket name isn't the real issue

Comment: After you ran the code, both buckets should have been created. My question is, after you ran the code did you look to see if both buckets actually got created? Did you go into the S3 console and look for both of those buckets? The reason I ask is because bucket names are global across all of AWS. You can't use an S3 bucket name that has already been used by someone else on AWS.

Comment: I did check, the successfully created bucket was there, it wasn't clear from the tutorial that each bucket should have a unique name across all AWS. Thanks for the information.